# Referrer url is being stripped out of header because of browser policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, referrer-policy

With the new release of the Chrome browser, version 85.0.4183.121, the referral url is now being stripped off when our on-line shoppers are redirected to Microsoft's Azure AD B2C in order to login. According to this article, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy, the fix is to set the Referrer-Policy on https://missionb2c.b2clogin.com.

I don't see any way to do this within AADB2C? Please help.

Our problem occurs only with the new version of Chrome: 85.0.4183.121. It does not happen in Edge or with older versions of Chrome.

The work around is to disable the “strict-origin-when-cross-origin” policy in Chrome:  chrome://flags/#reduced-referrer-granularity

However, we cannot use this as workaround – too many of our customers are experiencing this issue.

There is no error so I cannot send you a screenshot. Simply put, when shoppers are redirected to Microsoft’s b2c login page, the referral url is stripped out by the browser. This causes a ‘generic’ login page to be displayed instead of having our customer’s logo. Additionally, there is not option to “sign-up now” because this, too comes from the referral URL.

Comment: Currently it is not supported, please raise a support ticket with Microsoft for speedy assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Editing post:

This is a problem related to Chrome only.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default

You need to declare inside your anchor tag or inside in your javascript doc that the referrer policy you want is the no-referrer-downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using user flows to perform login, you can use a custom layout with your own html and css files as seen in here [customize user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow).
With that setup, you can add a script to your custom html adding a meta tag to set the referrer policy for you:

```
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = 'referrer';
meta.content = 'unsafe-url';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

or simply add it to your custom html:

```
<meta name='referrer' content='unsafe-url'></meta>
```

If you need referral information in Microsoft’s b2c login page that was being sending from your app before Chrome's update, than you'll need to add this tag to your site.

Edit: You may use no-referrer-when-downgrade to improve security, I've used unsafe-url because I'm doing this only in development